# How make an async RequestHandler in tornado python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado

currently I'm working on my Backend websserver using tornado.

The problem i have right now:
- when a request is made and the server is processing the request all other request are blocked

My RequestHandler:

```
class UpdateServicesRequestHandler( RequestHandler ):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get( self ):

        update = ServiceUpdate()
        response = yield update.update_all( )

        if self.request.headers.get('Origin'):
            self.set_header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', self.request.headers.get('Origin') )
        self.set_header( 'Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.write( response )
```

My `update_all()`:

```
@gen.coroutine
def update_all( self ):

    for service in self.port_list:
        response = yield self.update_service( str( service.get( 'port' ) ) )
        self.response_list.append( response )

    self.response = json.dumps( self.response_list )

    return self.response
```

My `update_sevice()`:

```
process = Popen( [ command ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True )
output, error = process.communicate()
```

The thing is, that I need the result of the `update_all()` method.
So is there a possibility to make this request not block my whole server for requests?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `update.update_all()` a coroutine? Does it use non-blocking I/O to do its work?

Comment: just updated my post..

Comment: Now we need to know what `update_service` looks like. :) Ultimately, we need to know if you're making a slow, blocking call somewhere inside `update_all`.

Comment: i'm using a subprocess `process = Popen( [ command ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True )` to run a generated command. Generally I'm calling 'git pull' commands on severall directories

Comment: Are you then waiting for the `Popen` command to finish? Because that will definitely block the event loop.

Comment: If you mean if I'm yealding it, then no. I'm just calling the command und the next command is: `output, error = process.communicate()`

Comment: Calling `process.communicate()` blocks the event loop until the command is done running. I'll add an answer on what you should do instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use tornado's wrapper around `subprocess.Popen` to avoid blocking the event loop:

```
from tornado.process import Subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def run_command(command):
    process = Subprocess([command], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    yield process.wait_for_exit()  # This waits without blocking the event loop.
    out, err = process.stdout.read(), process.stderr.read()
    # Do whatever you do with out and err
```

Comment: This really helped me out! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: Consider wait_for_exit( raise_error=False), otherwise a non 0 return from the subprocess will raise an exception.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using `tornado.process.Subprocess` as dano suggests, you should use `stdout=tornado.process.Subprocess.STREAM` instead of `PIPE`, and read from stdout/stderr asynchronously. Using `PIPE` will work for small amounts of output, but you will deadlock in `wait_for_exit()` if you use `PIPE` and the subprocess tries to write too much data (used to be 4KB but the limit is higher in most modern linux systems).

```
process = Subprocess([command], 
    stdout=Subprocess.STREAM, stderr=Subprocess.STREAM,
    shell=True)
out, err = yield [process.stdout.read_until_close(),
    process.stderr.read_until_close()]
```

Comment: What's the idiomatic way of getting the return code and raising an exception if non-zero in this case? Thanks -

Comment: `yield process.wait_for_exit()`: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess.wait_for_exit